# Rails 3 & validate_on_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3 warns me that validate_on_create is deprecated.  I have def validate_on_create in one of my models.  What do I replace it with?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use:

```
validates :name, :presence => true, :on => :create
```

If you have a method that performs validations, you should run as:

```
validate :method_name, :on => :create
```

Comment: My understanding is that the code I have validates the whole object.  Do you mean I have to separate this logic into multiple validation routines?

Comment: what about object.valid? method then after its pass you can continue with object.save